# MySQL Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I get an error for the below code! Please help

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

---

-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server

---

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`C_sshankaranar`@`%` PROCEDURE `SIT1_NullCheck`(IN tName Varchar(50),IN attribute Varchar(50),Out NullCount int(11),Out PC Varchar(200),Out x int(11))
BEGIN


set @Sl=NULL;

set @S1 = Concat('select count(*) into @NullCount from SIT1_STG.',tName,' where ',attribute,' is NULL or ',attribute,'=''');
Prepare stmt from @Sl; 
Execute stmt;

select SI into @x from dev2_stg2.Null_Check where Table_Name=tName;


If (@NullCount<>0) then

select Problem_Columns into @PC from dev2_stg2.Null_Check where SI=@x;

Update dev2_stg2.Null_Check  set Problem_Columns=Concat(@PC,' ',attribute) where SI=@x;


End IF;

Update dev2_stg2.Null_Check 
set Environment="SIT1_STG"
where SI=@x;

Update dev2_stg2.Null_Check 
set Update_Time=Now()
where SI=@x;

END
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like constructed SELECT query for prepared statement is incorrect.

The end of query has syntax error, something like this -

```
SELECT... or attr='
```

Output the query with another SELECT to check it -

```
BEGIN
  set @S1 = Concat...
  SELECT @S1;
END
```